# date time settings in vs2010 debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datetime, overflow

I use a query that takes in a datetime parameter such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE logindate=@logindate
```

Then I used parameter to pass in the @logindate value in C#

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logindate",DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
```

In my local, it works fine, but it gives error in my friend's local PC:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

We've tried many methods including Convert.ToDateTime but failed. When we checked in the debugger,

```
Datetime x = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

my PC gives "11/21/2012" whereas my friend's PC gives "21/11/2012" as the date. We've tried changing the date time of the PC, and checked the IIS 7.5 settings installed in our PC. Is there something else that we should check?